# sorting by DATE string MSSql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorting by date gives wrong output. The date that is being entered, is entered and stored as a string or rather Varchar(50), so when i sort it only takes the first part of example "22-11-2016" so "22". Too clarify: this is what my out is:

[image]

with the following query string:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CHECKEDIN, DATE
FROM timereg
WHERE UNILOGIN = @unilogin
ORDER BY DATE DESC, TIME DESC
```

and clearly column 9 should be on top because it is later that month.
how would i convert this somehow to datetime and sort it so it actually works, or just sort after the whole string.

-thanks

Comment: Use proper data types. Never store dates in varchar (or similar.)

Comment: this filed is not a date type, the date format for sql server is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: `ORDER BY convert(DATE,DATECOLUMN,105) DESC`

Comment: How can you get 9 rows of output when you have `Top 1` specified in your select statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your varchar to an actual date

```
... ORDER BY convert(date,DATE,103) DESC
```

Comment: Totally agree with the sentiment, but was kind of surprised that `103` works. The docs say `103 = dd/mm/yyyy` and `105 = dd-mm-yyyy`. Yet the result is the same. Weird.

Comment: @Leigh The separator seems to be second to the pattern  Try Select convert(date,'30-11-2016',103),convert(date,'30/11/2016',103),convert(date,'30.11.2016',103)

Comment: Yes, it definitely works. I was just surprised it handled the separator being different than expected/described in the docs. I'd probably use `105`, just for consistency sake, but .. learn something new every day :)

Comment: @Leigh Valid point.  I too learn something new every day.   That's the fun part.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, DATE, 105) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You will almost certainly take a performance hit, but you could try casting the column to a date type when sorting.

```
Order by  CONVERT(Datetime, [date], 103) Desc, time DESC
```